# How to allow click item during notifyDataSetChanged() in adapter

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview, adapter, android-viewholder

I use adapter in RecyclerView. Each item contains a ProgressBar. Since progress speed is sometimes very high, a fragment permanently call notifyDataSetChanged(), which initiates update adapter. But there is one unpleasant feature: at this time ViewHolder doesn't respond to a click and user can't open the item, while progress speed will not decrease. Is it possible to solve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

notifyDataSetChanged actually redraws the list for you. So click on the list item at that instant may actually refer to the content which was available before you refreshed the adapter contents. Hence its a good thing that click isn't enabled. Having said that, the refresh usually happens so quick that the user won't see a visible lag. Hence please go through you getView() method in the adapter if there is an intense or time taking process in the adapter implementation. Hope this helps! :)

Comment: Yes, but the `RecyclerView` adapter isn't have method `getView()`, it replaced `onBindViewHolder()` that i use.

Comment: @proninyaroslav How did you eventually solve it?

Comment: @HasIEluS I don't remember exactly :D I think the solution is to reduce the frequency of item updates